# How to write non-english characters to a file in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, encoding

I can't write any non-English characters to a file using NodeJs. Here's the code I use:

```
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Nämä', {encoding: 'utf8'}, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

The editor displaying the file is Notepad and it displays non-english characters as �.

Comment: If You using Windows then read about BOM

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't help. I can't find any solution

Comment: Please show `message.txt` content in HEX

Comment: Seems like node doesn't work like browsers. 
In browsers: "ä".test(/\u00E4/) == true
In node: "ä".test(/\u00E4/) == false

Comment: probably you save the file with your code in encoding other than UTF8